# how to cross-reference a manually incremented counter

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, tcolorbox

How to make the command `\ref{pb:p1}` work.

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.18cm,right=3.18cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{problem}[section]
\newcommand{\rproblem}[1]
{
\stepcounter{problem}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\textbf{Problem \arabic{problem}}}
\vspace{1em}
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!20!white,colframe=black!50!white,title=\textbf{Problem \arabic{problem}}]
#1
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\rproblem{\label{pb:p1}
My problem xxx.
}

This is answer \ref{pb:p1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`.

Comment: Make it a `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. But maybe you should let tcolorbox manage counters (`auto counter` and then in the title a `\thetcbcounter`).

Comment: @TeXnician Would you mind to add an answer?

Comment: Is there any reason why not using `tcolorbox` mechanism for numbered boxes with labels and adding it to a list of ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest to use either the `\newtcolorbox` macro in order to create the environment `rproblem` or `\newtcbox` to generate a box macro that behaves basically as the `\rproblem` macro by the O.P.

The counter is used from the definition as `problem` with `use counter=problem` and the `list of=toc` adds the box to the usual ToC, as subsection entries, since `\l@problem` was defined as being `\l@subsection`.

The label is given within the optional argument of `\rproblem` with `label=...`.

I provided both methods: With `\newtcbox` and `\newtcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=3.18cm,right=3.18cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{problem}[section]

\makeatletter
\let\l@problem\l@subsection
\makeatother

\tcbset{rproblem/.style={colback=black!20!white,
    colframe=black!50!white,
    title=\textbf{Problem \theproblem},
    before skip=1em}
}

\newtcbox[use counter=problem,number within={section},list inside=toc]{\rproblem}[1][]{
  rproblem,
  #1
}

\newtcolorbox[use counter=problem,number within={section},list inside=toc]{rproblemenv}[1][]{
  rproblem,
  #1
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Problems}


\rproblem[label={pb:p1}]{%
  My problem xxx.
}

\begin{rproblemenv}[label={pb:p2}]
  My problem xxx.
\end{rproblemenv}

This is answer \ref{pb:p1} or \ref{pb:p2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks. how to add the `\vspace{1em}`?

Comment: @aban: Add `before skip=1em` to the options of the boxes, but do you really mean `1em` and not `1ex`?

Comment: How to make the first `\rproblem` width as the second one. i.e. let 1.1 being `\linewidth`?

Comment: @aban: You can't since a `\tcbox` uses basically only the width that the content inside have. Only the environment version uses the fixed width of `\linewidth` (or any other one that has been specified before). The environment approach is the better one, in my point of view!

Answer (score 7):

If you do not want to use the `tcolorbox` approach you need to replace `\stepcounter` with `\refstepcounter`.

The reason for that is that `\label` uses `\@currentlabel` to find out what to refer to. And basically `\refstepcounter` sets this macro and increments the counter value.